# Problema em tentar listar erro -> " Trying to get property of non-object in"

Tags: php

Estou com o seguinte erro: Trying to get property of non-object in.

Que se encontra nesse trecho de código baixo.

```
<tr class="success">
      <td> <?=$reg->getServico ?></td>     ******//Erro se encontra nesta linha//************************
      <td> <?=$reg->getValor ?> </td>
      </tr>
```

Não sei do que se trata, se alguém puder me ajudar, segue o código abaixo:

**class servico dao.**

```
 <?php 
 require_once('./until/bd.class.php');
 $objBd = new bd();
 $con = $objBd->conecta_mysql();

class ServicoDAO{

     public function listar_servico( ){
     global $con;

     $servico_vo = new ServicoVO();
     $query = ("SELECT * FROM servico ");
     $stmt = $con->query($query);

     while ($rs= $stmt->fetch_array()) {
          $servico_vo->setIdServico($rs['id_servico']) ;
          $servico_vo->setServico($rs['nome_servico']) ;
          $servico_vo->setValor($rs['valor']);
          return $rs;
      }      
    }
}
```

Página que exibe os valores

```
    <body>

<div class="container">

       <div class="page-header">
         <h1>Listar Serviço</h1> 
       </div>


       <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed  ">

         <thead>
           <th>Produto</th>          
           <th>Fabricante</th> 
           <th>Preço</th> 
         </thead>

         <tbody>
          <?php

           $CPDAO = new ServicoDAO();
           $query = $CPDAO->listar_servico();

           foreach($query as $reg):


          ?>
          <tr class="success">
          <td> <?=$reg->getServico ?></td>     ******//Erro se encontra nesta linha//************************
          <td> <?=$reg->getValor ?> </td>
          </tr>


        </tbody>
      <?php 

      endforeach;
      ?>
      </table>


</body>
```

Comment: Pode colocar o erro completo? Em que linha é?

Comment: Cara já foi resolvido....O problema já esta na descrição é o erro  se encontra na linha descrita como "//Erro se encontra nesta linha//".

Comment: @junio parece ser o caso de [marcar uma resposta como aceita](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/). Aqui não escrevemos "resolvido" na questão. Se tem uma resposta que realmente te ajudou, marque-a como aceita. Se chegou sozinho à solução, poste a solução como resposta. Assim o conteúdo fica mais organizado e fácil de ser encontrado futuramente por outras pessoas com problemas parecidos.

Comment: Á sim desculpa ,  pensei que só escrever "resolvido" finalizava o post , mas eu marquei a resposta abaixo como aceita já , sem saber que era a solução.

Comment: Desculpe o transtorno , mas sou novo no fórum.                                       já editei o post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seu método listar_servico() não retorna um objeto, mas sim um array. Mas tem um detalhe: quando você dá um return $rs ali dentro do while, você está na mesma hora interrompendo o loop. Desta forma o while irá parar e definir o retorno $rs para o seu método assim que rodar o primeiro registro.

Faça da seguinte forma:

```
    $registros = array();
    while ($rs= $stmt->fetch_array()) {
              $servico_vo->setIdServico($rs['id_servico']) ;
              $servico_vo->setServico($rs['nome_servico']) ;
              $servico_vo->setValor($rs['valor']);
              $registros[] = $rs;
          }

   return (object) $registros; // Isso irá converter seu array $registros para um objeto
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta, mas esta me retornando o mesmo erro Trying to get property of non-object in.

Comment: Dê um var_dump($query) ali antes do foreach, pra eu ver como está ficando a estrutura

Comment: Esta me retornando todos os valores do array.                                                    object(stdClass)#6 (10) { [0]=> array(6) { [0]=> string(2) "21" ["id_servico"]=> string(2) "21" [1]=> string(2) "PC" ["nome_servico"]=> string(2) "PC" [2]=> string(7) "1500.00" ["valor"]=> string(7) "1500.00" } [1]=> array(6) { [0]=> string(2) "22" ["id_servico"]=> string(2) "22" [1]=> string(2) "PC" ["nome_servico"]=> string(2) "PC" [2]=> string(7) "2000.00" ["valor"]=> string(7) "2000.00" } [2]=> array(6) { [0]=> string(2) "23" ["id_servico"]=> string(2) "23" [1]=> string(8) "Formatar"

Comment: Os atributos getServico e getValor não estão definidos. Creio que você deva usar <?=$reg->nome_servico ?> e <?=$reg->valor ?>

Comment: Esta me retornando o mesmo erro.

Comment: e <?=$reg["nome_servico"] ?> e <?=$reg["valor"] ?> ? Acho que o array principal foi convertido para objeto, mas seus elementos não. Se isso aconteceu, só serão acessíveis desta forma. Tenta aí

Comment: Wallace Magalhães , muito obg.Deu tudo certo aqui.